# No entiendo la instrucciones de un Microprocesador, es el intel 8085

Tags: hardware

No entiendo muy bien el microprocesador, y no entiendo esta instrucción si alguien me puede ayudar, voy a estar muy agradecido.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es la instruccion que no entendes? y que tiene que ver la etiqueta hardware con esto?

Comment: el diagrama parece indicar que `ADI C` suma lo que hay en el registro `C` al acumulador ( registro `A` ), pero [según el instruction set](https://scanftree.com/microprocessor/Instruction-Set-In-8085)  para agregar registros (R) al acumulador A la instrucción es `ADD` onda `ADD C`